# Proportional scaling of divs

Tags: html, css

Does anybody have any ideas on how to make the same way of proportional scaling but with initial height value instead of width.

```
#container {
    position: absolute;

    width: 50px;

    top: 10px;
    left:10px;

    background-color: blue;
}

#container:before {
    content:"";
    display:block;
    padding-top: 100%;
}
```

The above code in a [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/453X9/5/)

Comment: Could you please elaborate a bit more on what it is that you're trying to achieve? Your question is currently vague.

Comment: Ok: The above css snippet is giving a div with a specific width, the same height, so its becoming a square.
I want the same but the other way round: you can see the result in the fiddle

Comment: Fiddle is updated! Was my first time using it and i forgot to update the link!

Comment: Note that your current fiddle doesn't work in Chrome. Could you explain what it is that you're trying to create in general, it looks like you're building a workaround.

Comment: i to giv a div a specific height like 100% and let the width be the same amount of pixels, so that it will be a square. BUT I don't know how many pixels the height will be. Thats why %

Comment: No its not duplicate because i want it the other way round. I reall was looking a lot for a answer but i only found this way of doing aspect ratio...

Comment: The second half of the linked question's accepted answer covers your question.

Comment: @Nit I hope you don't mind me nitpicking, but the question doesn't have an accepted answer.